# How do I cancel an exponent in an equation using siunitx?

Tags: equations, siunitx, cancel

The minimum working example below demonstrates the problem.  I have a number of equations formatted like the first one below, where say the numerator has square meters and the denominator has meters.  I would like to cancel the exponent but right now I have to say "m m" and cancel the first "m" which looks kinda dumb.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{cancel}
\begin{document}
    How can I cancel out the exponent in the numerator of the following equation?
    \begin{equation}
        W = \frac{\SI{32}{\square\meter}}{\SI{4}{\meter}} = \SI{8}{\meter}
    \end{equation}
    If instead of using \si{\square\meter} I use \si{\meter\meter}, it's easy:
    \begin{equation}
        W = \frac{\SI{32}{\cancel\meter\meter}}{\SI{4}{\cancel\meter}} = \SI{8}{\meter}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Obviously if it were meters cubed divided by meters, I'd want to cancel the 3 and follow it with a 2 but I haven't had that issue yet.  Thank you in advance!

Comment: I suppose you could bypass the `\SI` machinery entirely and write `W = \frac{32\,\mathrm{m}^{\cancel 2}}{4\,\cancel{\mathrm{m}}}`...

Comment: @Mico Bypassing `\SI` is a last resort.  There are other document reviewers who really like seeing the spelled-out stuff and who aren't up for the mental translation required to use your suggestion. :-(

Answer (score 2):

As Mico mentioned, it is probably easier to just skip `siunitx` all together and just set it manually. If you really do want to continue using `siunitx`, you can try and use some kerning to put the `\cancel` in the right place. For example, you can use the pair of macros<sup>1</sup> below to cross out the *final* subscript in a unit.

```
\usepackage{calc}

\newdimen{\KernAmount}

\newcommand{\cancelsup}[2]{%
  \setlength{\KernAmount}{\widthof{{\scriptsize \cancel{#1}}}*\real{-1}}%
  #2\kern\KernAmount\vphantom{}^{\cancel{\phantom{#1}}}}

\newcommand{\canceltosup}[3]{%
  \setlength{\KernAmount}{\widthof{{\scriptsize \cancel{#1}}}*\real{-1}}%
  #3\kern\KernAmount\vphantom{}^{\cancel{\phantom{#1}}}\vphantom{}^{^{#2}}}
```

The first just crosses out the exponent, while the second also places the replacement power in small text above the cancellation. For example:

```
\[
    W = \frac{\cancelsup{2}{\SI{32}{\square\meter}}}{\SI{4}{\cancel\meter}} = \SI{8}{\meter}
\] \[
    W = \frac{\canceltosup{3}{2}{\SI{32}{\cubic\meter}}}{\SI{4}{\cancel\meter}} = \SI{8}{\square\meter}
\]
```

[image: Screenshot of output for above code]

Notice that both need you to give a placeholder for the number you are going to cancel. This is to make sure the correct cancel shape and position occurs.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> As for every code snippet, this is only lightly tested and may break in unpredictable ways.</sub>